# Add permission to pull from aws ecr registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I have this default policy for aws ecr registry

```
{
  "Sid": "",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": ""
  },
  "Action": [
    "ecr:CreateRepository",
    "ecr:ReplicateImage"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:447619021764:repository/*"
}
```

Do you know how I can configure this json to allow pull from user?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the list of `erc` actions on:

- https://iam.cloudonaut.io/reference/ecr.html

Another great resource is the AWS Managed policies for ECR:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html

And

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policy-examples.html

The following examples show policy statements that you could use to control the permissions that authenticated users have to Amazon ECR repositories.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/push-pull-user-1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/push-pull-user-2"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I get `A policy statement may only specify Principal or NotPrincipal, but not both. Remove one and try again. @ Statement[0]`

Comment: You don´t have the principals listed in your example. Still, the error tells us that you either declare all principals using `Principal` or have a exclude rule with `NotPrincipal` (and allow everyone else). I updated the example to include users as principals.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the other answers resolve the question fully, if the permissions are being applied on a private registry at the top level then you can't add the policy for BatchGetImage. The only policies available at the top level seem to be - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry-permissions.html.

So the solution seems to be to either created separate policies in aws IAM for ECR or just apply the policies to the repositories themselves using the permissions mentioned in oieduardorabelo's answer.